# Number Pyramid In Java

Tags: java, numbers

Im sorry for bothering for this small thing but really i feel confused about this. I want to get output like;

```
        9
       89
      789
     6789
    56789
   456789
  3456789
 23456789
123456789
 23456789
  3456789
   456789
    56789
     6789
      789
       89
        9
```

But im taking my output after 123456789 line. My codes are;

```
for(int column = 1; column <= 9; column++) {
         for(int row = 1; row <= 9; row++) {
          if(column <= row) { 
              System.out.print(row);
          } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
          }
         }
         System.out.println(' ');

    }
```

Thanks For Your Attention.

Comment: There are more than nine rows, for starters. Also, have the row loop as the outer one.

Comment: Yes i've tried like that. But i got wrong input.

Comment: since you are the one providing the input ... or did you mean output?
in that case it might be handy to inform us what it is you actually get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit dirty, but gives the [desired output](http://ideone.com/ZGyJHN):

```
for(int column = -9; column <= 9; column++)
{
    if (column == 0) column = 2;
    for(int row = 1; row <= 9; row++)
    {
        if(Math.abs(column) <= row)
        { 
            System.out.print(row);
        } else 
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Np, also note that you switched the concept of rows and columns. Rows are horizontally and columns are vertically.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach that works

```
    String txt = "123456789";
    String msk = "         ";
    boolean done = false;
    boolean pos = true;
    int rows = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int maxrows=19;
    while (!done) {
        System.out.println(msk.substring(c) + txt.substring(9-c));
        if (pos) {
            c++;
            if (c>8) pos = false; 
        } else {
            c--;
            if (c<1) pos = true;
        }
        rows++;
        if (rows==maxrows) done = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way:

```
    int num = 9;
    int spaces = 8;
    boolean decreasingSpaces = true;
    for (int row=0; row < 17; row++) {

        for (int i=0; i < spaces; i++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        for (int j=num; j <= 9; j++)            
            System.out.print(j);

        System.out.println();

        if (decreasingSpaces) {
            spaces--;
            num--;
            if (spaces < 0) {
                decreasingSpaces = false;
                spaces += 2;
                num += 2;
            }
        } else {
            spaces++;
            num++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /*output:
   54321
    5432
     543
      54
       5
 */
 class NumberPyramid1
 {
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
        int n=5;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
           for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
              System.out.print(" ");
           }
           for(int k=n;k>=i;k--){
              System.out.print(k);
              //n--;
           }
           System.out.println();
           //n--;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: some explanation of what you are doing will help

Answer (score -2):

```
for(int column = 1; column <= 9; column++) {
     for(int row = 1; row <= 9; row++) {
      if(column <= row) { 
          System.out.print(row);
      } else {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
     }
     System.out.println(); // println will create a newline

}
```

Comment: But i don't need a new line. I just need to take output before 123456789 line.